# Export data from Wear OS watch without a companion app?

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I've built a Wear OS 2 app that (among other things) records waypoints using the watch's GPS. I'd like to export the waypoints, as a GPX file, to the paired Android phone. I think I understand how to do this using Channel Client and a companion app on the phone, but a companion app seems excessive in this scenario. Is there a mechanism for simply handing-over data to the phone and allowing the user to decide what to do with it (e.g. share, save, etc)?